# Putting Security around Sonatas Admin Extensions

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

I want to add a 'quick publish' function when saving pages in sonata admin - this function needs to be locked down to certain individuals with the correct 'role' or 'permission'.

I initially played around with changing the base template to add a form button and doing it all in the PageAdmin postUpdate/postPersist functions but felt this was a bit too messy.

I have now looked at using an AdminExtension - doing this meant removing the button from the form as I didn't really want to overwrite the template for this one change. To do this i've added a configureFormFields function:

```
public function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
{
    $formMapper->with('Options')
        ->add('quickPublish', 'checkbox', [
            'label' => 'Quick Publish',
            'required' => false,
            'help' => 'Checking this will automatically publish the changes'
        ])
        ->end();
```

}

I have then added my postPersist and postUpdate functions in here that will make the necessary updates.

```
public function postPersist(AdminInterface $admin, $object)
{
    if ($object->getQuickPublish()) {
        $this->quickPublish($object);
    }
}
```

The problem i'm facing is that I only want this admin extension to run based on the security roles not just all the time.

In postPersist and postUpdate it isn't an issue as I can use `$admin->isGranted('QUICK_PUBLISH)` but $admin isn't available to me in the configureFormFields function.

I can't find a way to put security around the admin extensions, anyone know how this works? I'm using Sonata 2.x

Thanks
Kevin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the built in [Sonata LockExtension](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/blob/3.x/Admin/Extension/LockExtension.php)

In the `configureFormFields` method, you should be able to get the admin object from the `FormMapper` :

```
public function configureFormFields(FormMapper $form)
{
    $admin = $form->getAdmin();
    //.....
}
```

Hope this helps